# MATLAB regexp matching '=' and numbers

Tags: regex, matlab

I'm writing a regexp to pick out punctuation in strings and I'm getting some behavior I don't expect:

```
ix = regexp('FGFR4','[~!@#$%^&*()-=+{}\|;:''",<.>/?\[]')
ix =

     [5]

ix = regexp('FGFR4','[~!@#$%^&*()-+{}\|;:''",<.>/?\[]') %note, the '=' is gone
ix =

     []
```

So it appears that '=' is matching the number 4.  What I expect is it only to match the '=' sign as so:

```
ix = regexp('FOO=SPAM','[~!@#$%^&*()-=+{}\|;:''",<.>/?\[]')
ix =

     [4]
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not the `=` but the `-` in front of it. It creates a range of all characters from `)` to `=` (in ASCII order). The reason why this is not a problem if you remove the `=` is that `+` comes before `4` in ASCII order, so the range does not include the `4` (in fact it only includes `)`, `*` and `+`, and since you have `*` anyway, this would have never mattered.

Three solutions:

1. escape the hyphen:

   ```
   [~!@#$%^&*()\-=+{}\|;:''",<.>/?\[]
   ```
2. or put it at the end of the character class:

   ```
   [~!@#$%^&*()=+{}\|;:''",<.>/?\[-]
   ```
3. unless you want to make sure that you use exactly this set of characters... so if you would be alright with matching anything that is not a space, a letter or a digit (or an underscore), you could just as well use this:

   ```
   [^\w\s]
   ```

   Matches any non-underscore, non-letter, non-digit, non-whitespace character.